# Is there a promise function in javascript that is similar to array.some?

Tags: javascript, promise

I see a bunch of promise functions like here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

but is there some function I can use that is similar to the array.prototype.some function? Something like this

```
var promises = [...]; // this is an array of promises
var containsTrue = await Promise.some(promises, x => x);
```

Resolves as `true` as soon as any of the promises resolves with `true`.  Resolves as `false` if all resolve as `false`.

If any promise rejects, it rejects immediately.

Does anyone know best way to implement this?

Comment: What should it do if one of the promises rejects?  I get that you're looking for the first one that resolves to true, but what it one or more rejects?  What do you expect the behavior to be in that case?

Comment: It should throw an error if any promise throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine [`Promise.any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) with an additional handler that throws if the value isn't true (or truthy, whatever logic you need).

```
await Promise.any(
  promises.map(promise => promise.then(
    (result) => {
      if (!result) throw new Error(); // Make this reject
    }
  ))
);
// will reject if all promises reject
```

Comment: If just 1 of the individual promises reject, will it throw an error? I think it will just return as false right?

Comment: Only if *all* reject (or all resolve with a falsey value) with the whole thing reject. So just one rejecting will be ignored if another one fulfills as truthy.

Answer (score 1):

Asssuming the spec is this:

1. Resolve immediately with the value of `true` as soon as any of the promises resolves as `true`.
2. Resolve with the value of `false` if all the promises resolve to `false`.
3. Reject immediately if any of the promises rejects.

Then, there is no specific built-in promise function that does that.  Neither `Promise.race()` nor `Promise.any()` matches that perfectly.

The problem with both `Promise.race()` and `Promise.any()` is that they both resolve as soon as any promise you've given them resolve.  They don't look for the resolved value to be `true`.  Per your spec, if a promise resolves to `false`, you want to keep waiting for another one to possibly resolve to `true`.  That, by definition, won't work with `Promise.race()` because it finishes whenever the first promise resolves or rejects which is just not what you want.

`Promise.any()` could be partially made to work by artificially changing a promise that resolves to false into a temporary rejection, but somehow keep track of whether it actually rejected or we just faked a rejection to keep `Promise.any()` from finishing.  But, there is no way to tell it to stop immediately when you get a real rejection because its design is to keep going until the end look for any promise that resolves, ignoring rejections unless they all reject.

So, `Promise.race()` stops too quickly when you want it to keep looking and `Promise.any()` won't stop quickly when you want it to.

So, here's how you can build your own implementation:

```
function PromiseSome(iterable) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let len = 0;
        let doneCnt = 0;
        for (let p of iterable) {
            ++len;
            Promise.resolve(p).then(result => {
                ++doneCnt;
                if (result === true) {
                    resolve(true);
                } else {
                    // if done with all of them
                    if (doneCnt === len) {
                        resolve(false);
                    }
                }
            }).catch(reject);
        }
    });
}
```

Or, if you want to ignore all rejections (just treat them the same as resolving `false`), then you can do this:

```
function PromiseSome(iterable) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let len = 0;
        let doneCnt = 0;
        for (let p of iterable) {
            ++len;
            Promise.resolve(p).catch(err => {
                // treat any rejection as just resolving false
                return false;
            }).then(result => {
                ++doneCnt;
                if (result === true) {
                    resolve(true);
                } else {
                    // if done with all of them
                    if (doneCnt === len) {
                        resolve(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Note, these are designed to look for the EXACT result of `true`.  If you want any truthy value to match, then you can change from `if (result === true)` to `if (result)`.